# FFmpeg What does flushing a codec do?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking at the examples of FFmpeg [Demuxing](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html), [Encoding](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encode_audio_8c-example.html). Whenever demuxing, encoding is finished codecs are flushed:

Demuxer:

```
 /* flush the decoders */
    if (video_dec_ctx)
        decode_packet(video_dec_ctx, NULL);
    if (audio_dec_ctx)
        decode_packet(audio_dec_ctx, NULL);
    printf("Demuxing succeeded.\n");
```

Encoder:

```
/* flush the encoder */
    encode(c, NULL, pkt, f);
```

I can not understand why the examples do this. It seems like sending nullptr as frame or packet does flushing but what is flushing? What does flushing a codec mean in the context of FFmpeg?